# How to write response data in CSV file with each row for one user in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, beanshell

I have a requirement to write 1 parent and 10 child ids in a Csv file. I'm able to get the values but couldn't write parent and child in a same row since another user data is being written in a same row. How can I achieve it.

Expected:
Parent1,child_U1_1,child_U1_2,...child_U1_10
Parent2,child_U2_1,child_U2_2,...child_U2_10
Actual:
Parent1,child_U1_1,child_U1_2,Parent2,Child_U2_U1, Child_U1_3...

Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're writing the data, but it looks like a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) to me

So

1. You either need to put the logic where you write the data into a file under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)
2. Or use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property to add the data you need to the JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)
3. Or alternatively go for i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) where you will have the full freedom to choose what, where and how to store.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, Critical section controller does the job.